# WP post and post_meta table issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In my WP post table there are images as attachment. i.e.  ID = 10 (this is parent post), and attachment post_parent = 10 (these are multiple records ).

Now i want to pick all post id with there children id and insert them into post_meta table i.e.

```
INSERT INTO rf_postmeta (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
     VALUES ("", "10", "gallery_", "11,12,13,14,15,16");
```

Can any one help me doing it with PHP ?

Comment: you probably are looking for the `INSERT INTO (field1, field2...) SELECT field1, field2 FROM TABLENAME WHERE condition` syntax. Or perhaps the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function of mysql, if you are trying to put them all into one rows one field. Please explain what the result you are expecting with a bit more detail.

Comment: Hi Tuncay,
below query is exactly the same. I want to enter  post_id  and  meta_value that will be picked from post table.
Inserting is not an issue, but getting value from post table is an issue then looping and inserting. 
INSERT INTO rf_postmeta (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) 
     VALUES ("", "10", "gallery_", "11,12,13,14,15,16");

Comment: what is not clear is do you want 10 rows in your `rf_postmeta` table each row with one child id in its meta_value field, or do you want 1 single row in your rf_postmeta with a comma separated meta_value string field ? In first case you can use a plain `INSERT INTO SELECT` , in second case you need a `GROUP_CONCAT` in that select. like: `INSERT INTO rf_postmeta(post_id,meta_value) SELECT post_id, group_concat(comment_id separator ",") from comments group by post_id` . untested sql, but something along those lines.

Comment: There will be  multiple records in  Post table   i.e.  ID 10 and then its  childern (11,12,13) ,  ID 14 and then its childern (15,16,17) etc.

for post meta table it will be  one row for   ID 10 and coma seprated values ,  then another row for ID 11 etc